# Daemon application permissions for a personal microsoft account

Tags: azure, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I am writing a daemon application to manage my personal microsoft outlook account, using the Outlook Mail REST API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations).
To do this I must generate the proper authorization token to use with the API calls.
I logged into the azure portal with my outlook account (xxx@outlook.com), and registered an application, created a client secret, and gave the app permission to User.Read.All for example.
I am using this example code to test my application:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2
I added my tenant-id, client-id, and client-secret from the application into the sample code, which successfully generates a token.
When the sample code makes a call to `graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` however, it returns this error:

```
Failed to call the Web Api: Forbidden
Content: {
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-08-08T20:47:59",
      "request-id": "ae8c7509-eada-41fd-90d7-dbb7885da534"
    }
  }
}
```

Is this due to the User.Read.All permission requiring admin consent? If so, am I not the admin for my own outlook account? Is there a more straight-forward way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have an Azure AD tenant where you registered the app.
So when you are trying to list the users, you are trying to list users in that Azure AD tenant.
You need to run admin consent in that tenant.
You can do that on the tab you defined the permission to the app *Grant admin consent*, or you can use the /adminconsent endpoint.

Comment: From the Overview page of Azure Active Directory in the Azure Portal, I can see that there is a AD tenant associated with my account. When I go to the page for that tenant's properties, however, I get a 403 error, resource not available.
When I try to use the /adminconsent endpoint, I get the error:
`
Selected user account does not exist in tenant 'Microsoft Services' and cannot access the application 'a59442bb-8f9d-4ae7-96ba-c57f539569a9' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Please use a different account.
`
@juunas

Answer (score 0):

You need to give consent to your application before accessing data.  To do that for a confidential client application (aka client credential flow) used in the daemon app sample you pointed at you need to be an administrator as you point out.

However, for Microsoft Accounts/personal accounts you are not an administrator of the tenant and therefore can't consent.

You will need to use delegated authentication instead.  You can use the refresh_token you get after authentication to get new access tokens when they expire.